# RSpec Running on Development DB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I inherited some RSpecs which I'm trying to run on a Rails 3.0 app, but I'm running into some issues.  For some reason, the RSpecs are running on my development database instead of my test database.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm calling my specs (in Windows), on the cmd line with:

```
bundle exec rspec foo_controller_spec.rb
```

My gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do  
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'pickle'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem "mocha", :require => false
  gem 'fixture_builder'
  gem 'ZenTest'
  gem 'assert_difference'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'term-ansicolor'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'assert_difference'
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'fixture_builder'
  require 'database_cleaner'
  require "authlogic/test_case" 
  require 'chargify_api_ares'
  require 'term/ansicolor'

    Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.mock_with :rspec
      config.color_enabled = true
      config.include AssertDifference
      config.include Webrat::HaveTagMatcher
      config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
      config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
      config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
      config.include AssertDifference
      config.include(MailerMacros)
      config.before(:each) { reset_email }

      config.before(:suite) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
        DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
      end

      config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.start
      end

      config.after(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
      end
    end
end

 Spork.each_run do
 end
```

Comment: What do you have in `config/database.yml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
rake spec
```

This is the way to run your RSpec in a rails project (at least usually).

Or

```
rake spec:controllers
```

for example, to run only the specs that regard to your controllers

Comment: thank you.  how do i get it to run for one controller script?